# Can I post to a Google+ community and to my circles at one time?

Tags: google-plus

If I post content to a private Google+ community to which I belong, is there a way to simultaneously post the content to my circles?

I know there are two setting for private G+ communities (community content is sharable or not), but is there a way to designate where my own posts end up, without having to post the same content twice (once to the community and once to my circles)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: no.

At the moment, you cannot post a message to your circles and to a community (public **or** private) at the same time. There are some legitimate concerns that if you do so you're exposing the community (or comments from members in the community) to people who are not in the community, and may not even be aware of its existence. While this may be ok for some private communities, it is probably not what most expect, which is a truly private place to talk.

Combining the two is a very tricky thing to navigate when it comes to private communities, and I don't expect them to address this issue further. But if you want to provide your input, and provide specific use cases where you think it makes sense and how you would like the privacy issues handled, make sure you use the *Send feedback* feature available under the gear icon.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround for this is to post to my circles, and then to share the post with the community.

Comment: Yeah, seems like a good workaround.

Comment: Can you show me the way how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

But if you post to your circles and then share to the community, it creates TWO copies on your profile page.

If the community is private, then I get it - but if the community is public - this make no sense.

Comment: Just uncheck the "Show your Google+ communities posts on the Posts tab of your Google+ profile." in the "Profile" section of your settings page.

Answer (score 0):

No, and as Chris mentioned above it is very annoying.

Post would be multiplied in your feed, which is bad for your popularity. *... our posts will not share the + counts or shares* is ridiculous, since two identical post will have different popularity ranks, one could have 1 like and the other could have 100 and they are exactly the same thing.

Comment: Just uncheck the "Show your Google+ communities posts on the Posts tab of your Google+ profile." in the "Profile" section of your settings page.